# How to pass parameters PHP with "/"

Tags: html

I was wondering how I could pass parameters to a PHP page like that : Imagine that I have a page "user.php", and every users have a unique ID in like 5 digits. So for example, for now I am writing "user?id=01234" to access the user 01234 page, but I would like to write "user/01234", which looks nicer, I think...

Any idea of how to do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you asking how to pass parameters through the URL? Or are you trying to echo these parameters?

Comment: If you are on apache then look into ModeRewrite in htaccess

Comment: You will need to handle the http routing so that all requests to user/* go to user, then in the php code take the id from the request string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many who are using PHP MVC-ish frameworks (Laravel, Zend 2/3, etc) that are going to dive deep into their well of knowledge about URL rewriting, routing, dispatch, and such to solve this problem. URL rewriting may be the way to go.

I do not know what you are using, your software architecture, or your security precautions. However, that said, the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` can be split with `explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` and you can get the user id that you want by retrieving the last element, which corresponds to highest index in the resulting array.

You will have to do some input validation and such, but, it could work. I would not recommend splitting `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and using the resulting array directly. Apply basic security processes first, then use it.

Also, remember that you can use `filter_input_array(INPUT_SERVER)` to use some built in `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` stuff.

I assume you were already doing some filtering and validating of the user ids, so you should be able to come up with a routine rather easily. It's all in how you handle the request, though.

One issue is that *by default* your web server (without any URL rewriting magic) will attempt to find a user id resource under the local webroot.

Example:

```
http://www.foo.com/user/01234/
```

This URL will instruct the HTTP server to look for an `index.php` *inside of a directory* named 01234/.

Since this *may not* exist, and you want pretty URLs, I would suggest learning about URL rewriting. This way, you can know what advanced users do and satisfy your goals.

[URL Rewriting with mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/)

Once you have this power, you will start seeing your web server in a new light. Coincidentally, this tends to lead you down the road to having a *centralized index.php* for a single point of entry into your application/website. Generally speaking, in that world you need to examine the request to determine which view you need to show the user.

You do not need a canned framework to do this, but some people will steer you towards one because frameworks have this *rewriting/routing/dispatching system* figured out. Ask some framework users to detail *the system* out for you, ah, now you discover who knows what is going on. Admittedly, I stumble a bit here too, but, I generally know what happens.

Lastly, I should mention that efforts to standardize how HTTP requests are handled in frameworks have been made. The PHP-FIG ([PHP Framework Interop Group](http://www.php-fig.org/)) has a standard called [PSR-7](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/). In truth, this makes more sense after you understand URL rewriting and SOLID principles of object-oriented design.

Basically, instead of having a bunch of scattered resources in PHP that relate to an HTTP request (`$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_SERVER`, `$_COOKIE`), I would say PSR-7 attempts to create an standard PHP, object-oriented interface to the information contained within an HTTP request. In theory, if frameworks comply with a PSR-7 standard, then one should be able to move from one framework to the next without having to dig deep to discover where essential HTTP request information is located.

Why bring that up? The point is that once you determine a way to get your pretty URLs, eventually, you will want to do it somewhere else, too. Create your own rewriting/routing/dispatching system and handle HTTP requests in a custom way, or creating as system that interfaces with a PSR-7 solution.

Suddenly, at this point, a canned framework sounds attractive to many. PSR-7 is not as easy to learn as PSR-2 (coding standards) and PSR-4 (autoloading of classes), but go ahead and start with URL rewriting. You'll be able to do something with that. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for this very precise and clear answer, it will help me a lot ! :)

Comment: This is perfect ! Thanks again so much

Comment: I can't because of my rep :'(